# " Invalid role specification `` " when importing a file that was just exported from phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database in phpMyAdmin where I have some views/sp/functions etc...

This week I decided to make a backup so I exported the whole thing and then tried to import again but the "error #1959 - Invalid role specification ``" keeps appearing whenever I do it. I really dont understand how can this program have difficulties importing something it has exported but I need to deliver this assignment very soon so any help is welcome :)))).

The error shows up near "CREATE DEFINER=`` PROCEDURE `is_Edition_Valid` (IN `year` INT)   BEGIN"

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.2.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Tempo de geração: 01-Dez-2022 às 23:22
-- Versão do servidor: 10.4.25-MariaDB
-- versão do PHP: 8.1.10

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Banco de dados: `fifa`
--

DELIMITER $$
--
-- Procedimentos
--
CREATE DEFINER=`` PROCEDURE `is_Edition_Valid` (IN `year` INT)   BEGIN

IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comitiva c 
   WHERE c.Ano = year) < 24 THEN
    SELECT 'Menos de 24 Comitivas' AS 'Edição Invalida:' ;
END IF;
```

I tried to search online for answers but I didn't find anything that could be useful

Comment: remove the definer if the logged in user is allowed to create it

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my problem if anyone is having it still.

Apparently phpMyAdmin doesn't translate well the views I create when Exporting so just check those lines in the sql file and it's good to go